# Sql Server Replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I get the following message when I want to create a Remote Distributor.
First i delete my whole configuration of replication then after i take a first step to create new replication and i get below error for creating a Distributor....[image]

I already do this but still same error........

```
sp_dropserver 'NODE-XYZ';
GO
sp_addserver 'NODE-XYZ', local;
GO
```

when run this command to get actual name then i get 'NULL' value

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
GO
```

Comment: I already do this but still same error........sp_dropserver 'NODE-XYZ';
GO
sp_addserver 'NODE-XYZ', local;
GO

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart your instance after doing sp_addserver in order to get a proper @@SERVERNAME response. [This is from BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174411.aspx):

> The local definition takes effect only after the Database Engine is restarted. Only one local server can be defined in each instance of the Database Engine.

Comment: What are the implications to any: live applications, SSIS packages, SSRS reporting, etc that may already be connected to the server? Is this going to interfere in any way? Will they all need to be updated?